# Matches on different words should score higher then multiple matches on one word in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, tagging

In our elasticsearch we have indexed some persons where each person can have multiple taggings.

Take for example 2 persons (fullname - (taggings)):

1. Bart Newman - (bart,engineer,ceo)
2. Bart Holland - (developer,employer)

Our searchquery

```
{
  "multi_match": {
    "type": "most_fields",
    "query": "bart developer",
    "operator": "or",
    "boost": 5,
    "fields": [
      "fullname^5",
      "taggings.tag.name^5"
    ],
    "fuzziness": 0
  }
}
```

Let's say we are searching on "**bart developer**". Then we should expect that Bart Holland should come before Bart Newman, but because Bart Newman has **bart** in his fullname and **bart** as tag, he scores higher then Bart Holland does.

Is there a way where I can configure that matches on different words (**bart**, **developer**) can score higher then multiple matches on one word (**bart**).

I already tried the **and**-operator without success.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is kind of expected with [`most fields`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/field-centric.html#_problem_1_matching_the_same_word_in_multiple_fields) query, it is *field-centric* rather than *term-centric*, From the Docs

> most_fields being field-centric rather than term-centric: it looks for
>   the most matching fields, when really what we’re interested is the
>   most matching terms.

Another problem is [`Inverse Document Frequency`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/field-centric.html#_problem_3_term_frequencies) which is also likely in your case. I guess only few documents have tag named `bart` which is why its `IDF` is very high and hence gets higher score.

As given in the above links, you should see how documents are scored with `validate` and `explain`.

There are couple of ways to solve this issue

1) You can use [custom _all](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/custom-all.html) field, i.e copy both `full name` and `tag` information to new field with `copy_to` parameter and then query on it but you have to `reindex` your data for that

2) I think better solution would be to use [cross fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_cross_fields_queries.html), it takes `term-centric` approach. From the Docs

> The cross_fields type first analyzes the query string to produce a
>   list of terms, and then it searches for each term in any field.

It also solves `IDF` issue by blending it across all fields.

This should solve your issue.

```
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "type": "cross_fields",
      "query": "bart developer",
      "operator": "or",
      "fields": [
        "fullname",
        "tagging.tag.name"
      ],
      "fuzziness": 0
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!